# Can Flutter allow access to widgets in native code?

Tags: android, swift, user-interface, realm, flutter

I have an app I'm wanting to try out in Flutter but one major thing may hold me back. Our app will need to access and edit the layout in code depending on what comes from saved data. A user can choose to leave something disabled, and those settings will be saved in a Realm.

Is this something that's possible with Flutter? I know it works with native code, but haven't been able to find anything yet indicating that native code can access widgets build in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Realm has a native Android and iOS plugin. With Flutter, you can use a `MethodChannel` to execute native code. So you could create a Realm wrapper for Flutter using native code.
In short: Yes it is possible.

This is a useful link if you end up creating a wrapper: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/